# Rasbian(ARM) in Qemu emulator with Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init

Tags: linux, virtualization, virtual-machines, kernel, qemu

I am using `qemu` 2.6.0 on my ubuntu 14.04 x86_64 PC.
But it fails with a kernel panic error.

I want to emulate `rasbian` -- A Linux destro based on ARM Debian for Raspberry Pi.

Here's the settings when using `qemu`

```
/usr/local/src/qemu-2.6.0/bin/debug/native/arm-softmmu/qemu-system-arm \
    -kernel /path/to/kernel-qemu-4.4.11-jessie \
    -m 256 \
    -cpu arm1176 \
    -M versatilepb \
    -no-reboot \
    -serial stdio \
    -hda /path/to/2016-05-27-raspbian-jessie.img \
    -append "dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 root=/dev/sda2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait selinux=disabled" \
```

And the error log is:

[image]

The kernel is derived from here:

> https://github.com/dhruvvyas90/qemu-rpi-kernel

Disks are recognized correctly.

How can I boot this image correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright. I have to answer this question before anyone else.

I followed this tutorial. https://blog.3mdeb.com/2015/2015-12-30-emulate-rapberry-pi-2-in-qemu/

The key is that **Changing ld.so.preload**

Then it boots.

[image]

Then I think I can do a lot things using qemu `new.sh`.

Here's the commands:

```
/usr/local/src/qemu-2.6.0/bin/debug/native/arm-softmmu/qemu-system-arm \
    -kernel /path/to/qemu-rpi-kernel/kernel-qemu-4.4.11-jessie \
    -m 256 \
    -cpu arm1176 \
    -M versatilepb \
    -no-reboot \
    -serial stdio \
    -append "earlyprintk loglevel=8 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 root=/dev/sda2 rootfstype=ext4  rootwait init=/bin/bash" \
    -drive file=/path/to/2016-05-27-raspbian-jessie.img,format=raw \
```

But I am still looking for solution without changing any file of the official rasbian image.

## Where's 100% pure solution?

Comment if you have an idea! :)

Comment: You saved my day I guess!

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix you're welcome :)